# substract two dates using sql loader

Tags: sql-loader

I Have two dates. One is **cur_phy_date** and next one is **Last_Phy_Date**. But problem here is flat file has only one date i.e.,**cur_phy_date** but to calculate **Last_Phy_Date** I need to substract 6 months from **cur_phy_date** in SQL LOADER control file.
My sample date formats for **cur_phy_date**: 2018MAY01.

Is it possible to substract 4 or 5 months from cur_phy_date and get **Last_Phy_Date** in the same format as **cur_phy_date**

Comment: What's the data type of the date's in the table?  If varchar2, do you have the power to make them a proper DATE datatype before continuing?  Don't worry about the format in the data file, that can be converted on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have the power to make your columns a proper DATE datatype.  If not, well, we all have to work with a bad design at one point or another.  Either way, you need to convert the current date to a proper date by referencing it with a preceding colon character, subtract 6 months, then convert to the format you need.  Here's how your control file entry should look:

To a proper date:

```
Last_Phy_Date  date "MM/DD/YYYY" "TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:cur_phy_date , 'YYYYMONDD'),-6), 'MM/DD/YYYY')",
```

To a VARCHAR2:

```
Last_Phy_Date  CHAR "TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:cur_phy_date , 'YYYYMONDD'),-6), 'YYYYMONDD')",
```